# bundle install does not install gems specified in Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, capistrano, bundler

`Bundle install` run by capistrano on my web-server does not install the gems specified in `Gemfile.lock`.

I have passenger 4.0.41 specified in Gemfile.lock, but when I look at the output of capistrano's `bundle install` it does not install it, it keeps the previous version `passenger 4.0.40` in use.

Comment: So far I've discovered that I need to `cap deploy:update` and then run `cap bundle:install` and then deploy again, for the gems to be installed, it was still using the old deploy's Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 1):

In your first sentence, you have Gemfile.lock**1**. It doesn't matter what version of passenger is specified in that file, since bundle reads Gemfile.lock. (Notice the lack of a one at the end).

See the bundle install man page (http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/bundle-install.1.html) for more info.